# Moved comments to chat now answer is gone

Tags: support

A user had provided an answer to the following question on StackOverflow.
[Need to pass windows credentials cross domain to API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148984/need-to-pass-windows-credentials-cross-domain-to-api)

We started commenting and so I moved it to chat, however this removed his answer and subsequent comments from the original question.

How do I get the answer back into the question as it was useful for other users to see.

Comment: The answer was probably removed by mods or self-deleted but since I'm not 10k, I can't say why.

Comment: The answerer deleted his answer himself, and you accepted the other answer (with praise). Are you really sure that forcibly undeleting that answer would bring something to the question?

Comment: Simply ask the user to undelete his answer in chat, the room still exists and if you'll use `@` in there he'll be notified.

Answer (score 4):

Moving comments to chat doesn't affect the post they're attached to.  (In the moderator "move comments to chat" interface it doesn't even delete the comments on the post automatically.  The "let us continue this in chat" interface does delete the applicable comments on the post.)

If the post is gone it's because it was explicitly deleted -- by the author, the community (through votes), a moderator, or, if downvoted, possibly by an automated community process.  According to the comments here, this particular answer was deleted by its author.